# Some devices don't match standard drawable Android ratios

Tags: android, splash-screen, android-drawable

In one of our apps there is a splash screen during loding of app data. The customer have delivered the images which shoud be shown in the splash activity. All in all 6 images for 6 drawable sizes:

- ldpi (240x320)
- mdpi (320x480)
- hdpi (480x800)
- xdpi (640x960)
- xxdpi (960x1440)
- xxxdpi (1280-1920)

The problem is that some devices fall outside these ratios. For example Samsung Galaxy S4 and it's 'Active' model both have screen size of 1080x1920 which falls between these ratios thus squizzing the image to fit the view as can be seen in the screenshot where the image is squizzed horizontally.

What can I do? Where can I place a 1080x1920 image outside these 6 drawables?

[image: Image is squizzed horizontaly]

Comment: No response after 20 hours. Have I stumbled onto a major issue here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Galaxy S4 (1080×1920) takes the *xxhdpi* drawable. The screen aspect ratio is 9:16, but the given drawable is of 2:3, hence the stretch.

We have hundreds of different screen resolutions out there, so you can't really satisfy them all.

I can think of:

1. stretching the drawable as you already did **losing the original aspect ratio**,
2. cropping/shrinking the drawable with a different [`ScaleType`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html) (`FIT_XY` is default in `ImageView`) which might look ugly,
3. or using [`nine-patch`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html#nine-patch) if both options are unacceptable.

With option #2, you may go with `ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE` and set a plain background with a greenish color for example.